# HTTP POST/GET via stdio

Tags: c++, c, http, stdio

Is it possible to communicate with server via raw file IO functions like `fprintf()` and `fscanf()`?

E.g. this code won't work afaik:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("http://example.com/", "r");

    while (!feof(f))
    {
        char *s = new char[255];
        fscanf(f, "%s", s);
        printf("%s\n", s);
        delete[] s;
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this won't work, that's not what `stdio` is for. But I tell you what you can do:

- Use libcurl
- Use asio
- Use your own sockets

I don't know about win32, but on Unix you could:

- Get a socket to that host using [`connect(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html)
- Use [`fdopen(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) to associate it with a `FILE *`

Also, those functions aren't "raw" at all; there's quite a lot going on before the really raw stuff is called (the system calls).

Answer (score 0):

Not by STDIO by itself, you have to have something open the socket.